# Which is more appropriate, saving data in the database or saving data in a file?

Tags: mysql, sql

Let's suppose I own a database. This database has some tables. One of this tables (USER_VALUES) has three columns: **valueId(PK), userID(FK), categoryId(FK), value(NUMBER)**.

Everytime I insert a new user, a trigger inserts 50 rows in USER_VALUES table for that specific user.

Is it effective? What is the best way to store this data? A user can insert an unlimited number of values in that table, so I suppose the more users that have registered the slower it will work the selectByUser query.

Comment: Do you think it will be faster when you store that data in a file? Simply index the table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Databases generally store their data in files, so the answer to this question could be shortened to 'Yes'.

The question you really should be asking is: "Can I write a specialized database specifically for this use-case that will be faster than a general database engine". The answer to that is "Maybe".

How will you know? One way would be to give it a shot and measure to see if you did a better job than your database. My guess will be that this is not the case.

Personally, when I look at your specific case (a key->value table and probably duplicating values from a normalized user table) I would wonder why you would do that in the first place. What's the point? It sounds like a bad way to use a RDBMS.  If your justifications make sense though, chances are that there's is either a better way to do it with your database engine, or a different type of data-store that is more optimized for your use-case.